# Catching / capturing chrome storage sync errors

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

If we use this code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({settings: x}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
});
```

what is the best way to capture an error, is this the right way?

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({settings: x}, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          return cb(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        console.log('Settings saved');
        cb(null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a best way to capture errors with usage of all chrome async API.

Using `try ... catch` in your callback won't help. Also,

It's async, so using `try` around the original API call won't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You could promisify it to manage errors and callback hell better.

```js
    var promisify = function (fn) {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fn.apply(null, args.concat(function (res) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          }
          return resolve(res);
        }));
      });
    };
```

then you can use it as follows:

```js
    function setStorageItems(items) {
      return promisify(chrome.storage.sync.set, items);
    }
    
    setStorageItems({settings: 'x'}).then(function() {
      console.log('settings saved');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: yes that's the plan, the question was just about how to access the error, since it doesn't seem to be an error-first callback, so I guess `chrome.runtime.lastError` is the best way to get the relevant error